How the randomisation probability is updated for each new patient entering adaptive clinical trial?
Disclaimer: You may need to read the entire paper to answer this question :)
I am reading this paper to learn about adaptive clinical trials. Here in page 1723 under "Statistical methods" section we can see

When
each new patient entered the trial, qk , which was defined as Pr(mk < m0
data), where k = 1, 2; and r, defined as Pr(m1 < m2 data), were calculated
to evaluate the stopping rules and to adapt the randomization probabilities.

I am particularly interested in calculating Pr(mk < m0 ; data). Does anyone know how is it calculated with a simple example?
Thing that confuses me: Patient 1 gets enrolled on 4/3/01 and Patient 2 gets enrolled on 4/11/01. Now even though we don't know if Patient 1 is a success (which we will know only after 50 days as per the rules of the trials set for patients success) there is an update in probability for arm1 and arm2.

The response is in the statement:

The comparison of arms in the data analysis and
for the adaptive randomization was based on time to success, which we
assumed was exponential, but which was truncated at 50 days.

In other words, the authors considered a time-to-event analysis that accommodates partial information. More specifically, they assumed that time to CR without grade 4 follows an exponential distribution. In the example given by you, patient 1 has 8 days out of 50 without a complete response, so patient 1 will be considered as censored. This partial information was used to recalculate the randomization probabilities.

I understand from your response that partial information was used however what bugs me is the maths behind it. Can you help me with or point me to some materials?

You can read more about survival: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~madigan/W2025/notes/survival.pdf
